# jQuery Add / remove class on nav

Tags: jquery

How can I create different classes on my links so they can show different images when you click on them?

The idea is that the links has its own color and when it is active there must be a little arrow with the same color.

This is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="red"><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
    <li class="blue"><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red {background-color:#f00; }
.red_bnt { background-image:url(image/red_bnt_pil.png); }

.blue {background-color:#00f; }
.blue_bnt { background-image:url(image/red_bnt_pil.png); }
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">

$('.red').click(function(){
    $('.red').removeClass('red_bnt');
    $(this).addClass('red_bnt');
});

</script>
```

And then repeat it for the blue as well.

But it is not working ...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you removing a class that doesn't exist then re-adding it?

Comment: Describe how must function work, is there any other elements?

Comment: If the first link is active it must have the class red_bnt and if you click on second link the red_bnt class must be removed. 
Is this not how the code works?

I am newbie to jQuery so I probably did not understand it right.

Comment: Add additional html or better: use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Jmav:

It's actually just a hover and active effect I am looking for.
but the menu buttons are in different colors so i need to add som classes whit bg images of a arrow in the same color as the menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.red').click(function(){
    $('.red').removeClass('red_bnt');
    $(this).addClass('red_bnt');
});
```

Your jQuery is saying that when an element with the class "red" is clicked, remove class "red_bnt" from all elements with the "red" class and then add red_bnt to the clicked element. Since the blue button doesn't have the class red, it never even enters the equation. Instead, add a common class to the buttons and then a use a common class name, such as "active", which would activate the background CSS.

I'd change your CSS to:

```
.red.btn {background-color:#f00; }
.red.hover,
.red.active { background-image:url(image/red_bnt_pil.png); }

.blue.btn {background-color:#00f; }
.blue.hover,
.blue.btn.active { background-image:url(image/blue_bnt_pil.png); }
```

The HTML to:

```
<ul>
    <li class="red btn"><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
    <li class="blue btn"><a href="#">Link two</a></li>  
</ul>
```

and the jQuery to:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
$(function() {
    $('li.btn').click(function(){
        // Add "active" to the clicked element and
        // get all siblings and remove "active" from them
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });

    // Use this for hover
    $('li.btn').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's a jsFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/FS4Du/. I used the colors darkred and dodgerblue in place of your images.

*Note: I used the hover class instead of just reusing active to avoid having to handle the case where the element that was clicked on (the active element) is then hovered over.*

Comment: That explain why my code did not work. Thank you.


I've tried what you wrote but nothing happens when I click the links

Is it because the space between ="red bnt" ?

Comment: It seems like the class is not added

Comment: @kasper well first, notice that I used "btn" not "bnt", that might be it. Second, the space between them indicates that they are two distinct classes (a "red" class and a "btn" class).

Comment: I notices the bnt btn issue.. 
But if i copy the code from http://jsfiddle.net/FS4Du/ in to a html document and load it in my browser it doesn't work. 
i try with : jquery-1.4.4.min.js and jquery-1.6.2.js and nothing is heppend verry verry weird

Comment: @Kasper have a look at the source of http://so.savantcoding.com/csslist/. I put it all on one page for you.

Comment: Ahh i was missing a ; in the script.. Thank you that relly help !!

Comment: @Kasper glad to help! don't forget to accept the answer since it worked to solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

i thing ur using same image for both class,,

```
.red_bnt { background-image:url(image/**red_bnt_pil.png**); }

.blue {background-color:#00f; }
.blue_bnt { background-image:url(image/**red_bnt_pil.png**); }
```

......................................

Comment: Typing fail :) Sorry. (image/blue_bnt_pil.png)